# How to clean up bad values (any values that aren't rounded to the nearest hour) in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

So... I have a bunch of values in my column that have the following format:

```
23-FEB-18 11.42.41.065000000 AM
```

I am trying to only allow values that look like the following:

```
19-APR-19 06.00.00.000000000 AM
```

I have tried the following:

```
delete from table_name 
where DATETIME not like '%00.00.00000%';
```

But this deletes 0 rows. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: are you exactly looking for all zeros after the first dot (.) in your time value?

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: @jarlh it's a timestamp

Comment: @ErayBalkanli yes, but i've tried just using 2 zeroes as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DATETIME` is a timestamp, but you treat it as if it were a string.

You want to delete all values that change when you truncate to hours:

```
delete from table_name 
where datetime <> trunc(datetime, 'hh');
```